# Integral over a hypersurface

Tags: special-relativity

In Landau-Lifschitz(Volume 2) is given

Integral over a hypersurface, i.e. over a three-dimensional manifold. In three dimensional space the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by three vectors is equal to the determinant of the third rank formed from the components of the vectors. One obtains analogously the projections of the volume of the parallelepiped (i.e. the "areas" of the hypersurface) spanned by three four-vectors $du^i, dv^i, dw^i;$ they are given by determinants 
\begin{equation*}
dS^{ikl}=
\begin{vmatrix}
du^i & dv^i & dw^i\\
du^k & dv^k & dw^k\\
du^l & dv^l & dw^l
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation*}
which form a tensor of rank 3, antisymmetric in all three indices.

If it is three-dimensional manifold why it is called a hypersurface? What is actually a hypersurface? How are the projections of the volume of the parallelepiped can be the "areas" of the hypersurface?

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2879567/intuition-or-motivation-for-the-definition-of-an-hypersurface-what-are-we-actua?rq=1) on Math.SE answers your confusion I think.

Comment: I was looking for the answer in mathematics for physicists language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hypersurface is another name for a [codimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codimension)-1 manifold. That is, it is a manifold whose dimension is one less than that of the ambient space. In 3D this means a hypersurface is a (3-1)=2D manifold ie a regular 'surface'.

Hypersurfaces arise frequently as the boundaries of manifolds. The boundary of a manifold-with-boundary is a manifold (without boundary) of one lower dimension than the original manifold. For example the boundary of the 3-ball $B^3=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1\}$ is the 2-sphere $S^2=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$.

The words 'volume' and 'area' are themselves confusing as they can mean either 3-dimensional (or 2-dim respectively) measures OR they can be used in the sense that volume is the 'top' measure. In this sense, an integral over a 4D region of 4D spacetime is a 'volume integral'. Since 4D regions are bounded by 3D hypersurfaces, the 'surface area' is given by some triple integral, but it still makes sense to call it an area, not a volume.

One setting where this all comes up is the general case of [Stoke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem), which states that a volume integral of the derivative of a function can be related to a surface integral of that function. This theorem holds in any number of dimensions and it would be silly to have to give them all names, so we tend to call the highest dimensional integral a 'volume' and the next highest a 'surface area'.

Comment: Note that this answer contains no physics and purely discusses terminology. As such I don't know if it should stay.

Comment: What would hypersurface of a parallelopiped embedded in 4D?

Comment: Landau means that (anagously to a 2-surface being split up into 2-dim parallelograms) a 3-surface can be split into many tiny area elements, each of which is a 3-dim parallelopiped.

Comment: How to imagine a 3D surface intuitively?

Comment: That is I think a new question, and one for the Maths stack. Formally of course its defined as a limit of sums in the same way as any other integral. Intuitively, my approach would be to just pretend its a 2D surface integral and only worry about the details if they become important...

Comment: I think the surface of the floating bubbles in the air is 3D surface if they are altering their shape. But I am not confident with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102883/discussion-between-constantin-and-jacob1729).